# Dependency injection Scoped into Transient and then Transient into Singleton

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have a `scoped` `Context` that is being accessed from `transient` service through method.
This `transient` service is being injected into `singleton` service.

Will my `scoped` `Context` become singleton or will it stay scoped?

```
public class Context : IContext
{
    public string CorrelationId { get; set; }

    public Context(string id)
    {
        CorrelationId = id;
    }
}
```

Context accessor:

```
internal class RequestContextRegistrator : IRequestContextRegistrator
{
    private IContext context;

    public IContext RegisterContext(IContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;

        return context;
    }

    public IContext Get()
    {
        return context ?? new Context()
        {
            CorrelationId = context.CorrelationId
        };
    }
}
```

And Singleton object:

```
public class QueueSender<TCommand> 
{
    private readonly IRequestContextRegistrator provider;

    public QueueSender(IRequestContextRegistrator provider)
    {
       this.provider = provider;
    }

    public async Task Send(TCommand command)
    {
        var context = provider.Get();

        var message = PrepareServiceBusMessage(command, userAgent, context?.CorrelationId);

    }
}
```

The whole idea is to be able to pass around context id that is unique to the particular "request". The request is not coming from `dotnet` controller, it comes from queue receiver class.

Or to paraphrase it, how deep does this conversion to singleton goes for tree of dependency injections.

Answer (score 2):

Do not resolve a scoped service from a singleton. It may cause the service to have incorrect state when processing subsequent requests. It's fine to:

- Resolve a singleton service from a scoped or transient service.
- Resolve a scoped service from another scoped or transient service.

please see this link [Service lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-lifetimes)

Answer (score 0):

> Will my scoped Context become singleton or will it stay scoped?

It will stay scoped.

Your singleton instance will have a `RequestContextRegistrator` injected which will in turn have a `Context` injected; this `Context` instance will exist until your app terminates, as the singleton will preserve its reference, however, any other class that requires an `IContext` will have a *new* `Context` injected.

Comment: Wouldn't that lead to memory leak eventually?

Comment: The singleton and its dependencies will only be garbage collected when the containing `AppDomain` is unloaded; because you are creating a singleton, you are explicitly requesting this behaviour. There are only 3 instances involved so it shouldn't cause memory issues.

Comment: With every queue message there will be a new `context`, if service consumes 1.000.000 messages ain't that a problem?

Comment: What is a queue message? You haven't shared any other class that has `IContext` as a dependency.

Comment: `QueueSender` sends queue message.